# Adding new tick label names to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have changed abbreviated names of my factor levels to full titles with the following script:

```
Est.labs <- c("Ocean_Bal","CLR","GGR", "HKR", "HUR", "MLR", "PST", "RMR", "SHR", "Ocean_Yam")
names(Est.labs)<- c ("Ballina inshore", "Clarence River", "Georges River","Hawkesbury River","Hunter River", "Macleay River", "Port Stephens", "Richmond River", "Shoalhaven River", "Yamba inshore")
```

I now want to add these new names to the following plot i.e. `+labels=names(Est.labs)`, but am not sure where it belongs, as it would normally be in the `scale_x_discrete` section; this is already in the script however:

```
p2<-p1 +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Northern" = "firebrick4", "Central" = "dodgerblue4", "Southern" = "darkseagreen4"))+ scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)+ theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data_long$Concentration-se_long$se, ymax=data_long$Concentration+se_long$se), width=.2,
                 position=position_dodge(.9))+ylab("Concentration (µmol/mol)")
```

It's probably simple but I'm not having any luck trying different things...any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just add your `labels=` argument directly in `scale_x_discrete()` along with your `limits=` argument you already have there and it should work.  You may also need to specify `breaks=` based on your data.  Without seeing what `p2` looks like or the full code to generate your plot, it's difficult to help more specifically.

Comment: Thanks a million....I finally got by switching the two around:p2<-p1 +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Northern" = "firebrick4", "Central" = "dodgerblue4", "Southern" = "darkseagreen4"))+ scale_x_discrete(labels=names(Est.labs), limits = positions)+ theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data_long$Concentration-se_long$se, ymax=data_long$Concentration+se_long$se), width=.2,
                 position=position_dodge(.9))+ylab("Concentration (µmol/mol)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1, vjust = 1))

Comment: The only problem now is the tick labels look a little strange. I wish I could show you but I can't attach a snip or image of the plot. The letters in each word are slightly unevenly spaced and not totally aligned. It's gives them a kind of "wriggly/wobbly" appearance

Comment: If you add the plot, someone will activate it for you.

Comment: OP, we would really like to help you and probably could find a solution to your problem; however, there's not much we can do without at least seeing the plot.  In the case where we cannot see your plot, you can help us re-create it by:  (1) sharing your dataset.  Do this by typing `dput(your_df)` into the console, then copying and pasting the output of that function into your question.  (it will start with `structure(...`).  If the dataframe is too large, you can use `sample()` or `head()` to reduce the side and share that.  (2) Share the code used to create `p1`.

Comment: Also: if you want to share an image of your plot but cannot yet (b/c of your lack of enough reputation on SO), upload the image to an image-sharing site (like [imgur](https://imgur.com/)) and then paste the link into your question.  We would then help to edit your question and embed the image for you.

Comment: Great feedback!!!

Comment: This first image refers to the odd appearance of the tick labels: https://imgur.com/F7sxlIT                               this is when I add the script:                                                                     +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1, vjust = 1))

Comment: I have managed to get it looking better: https://imgur.com/nmrO4RS                                                         with this script: +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1, vjust = 0.1))

Comment: Thanks for the pictures - so your what do you find odd about the tick label appearance?  And just to be clear, the question is about the apperance of the ticks / text rather than the labels themselves, right?